# Android - Conditionally Access Jar

Tags: java, android, jar

I have a JAR that is only able to be accessed by a certain line of phones.

Is there a way to conditionally call code that references that JAR so that I don't get linkage errors when other phones do not have that?

E.G.

```
if(JARisAvailable)
    functionFromJAR();
else
    functionNotFromJAR();
```

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense. On Android, the JAR is a compile-time construct, not a runtime construct. Is this some sort of vendor SDK add-on (e.g., you are using `<uses-library>`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mean a JAR. The JARs are all delivered in your APK. You are referring to packages which may or may not be available within the framework based on the particular API level that the device has.

You can do this, of course, but you need to do it in a specific way. You need to put all the code that uses APIs that may not be available into a separate class (or classes). You need to check if the device supports the API you want to use. If it does, you can then create an instance of the separate class (or classes) and use them.

The secret here is that the Virtual Machine (VM) verifies classes (ie: checks that all the classes they use exist and all the methods they call exist, etc.) ONLY when the class is loaded, and the VM only loads a class when it is first used (new instance creation or a static member referenced or a static method called). As long as you avoid loading a class that uses non-existent classes or methods you won't have a problem.

See http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html for an example.